# Alternative way to check cauchy riemann equation.

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a function $$f(z)=\begin{cases} 
e^{-z^{-4}} & z\neq0 \\
0 & z=0
\end{cases}$$

I have to show cauchy riemann equation is satisfied everywhere. I have shown that it isn't differentiable at $z=0$.

Usually I will have to convert it in $$f(z)=u+iv$$ which seems very tedious. Is there some way to do this while keeping it in $f(z)$ form.

Comment: You don't need to know u(x,y) abd v(x,y) for all (x,y). You just need u(x,0), u(0,0),v(0,y),etc in order to compute the partial derivatives using the definiton

Comment: In order to get u(x,0) plug in z=x and you'll get f(x)=e^(-x^4)=u(x,0)+iv(x,0). By equating the real parts pf both sides you get u(x,0) and by equating the imaginary parts of both sides you get v(x,0)

Comment: @zokomoko can you elaborate. How does one find partial derivative of u using u(X,0) u(0,0) and v(0,y)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the question asks to use Cauchy-Riemann equations so either you convert it to get $u$ and $v$  in $x$ and $y$; or use polar coordinates $r$, $\theta$ using $z=re^{i\theta}$, i.e.

$f(re^{i\theta})=e^\frac{-cos 4\theta}{r^4}cos(\frac{sin 4\theta}{r^4})+ie^\frac{-cos 4\theta}{r^4}sin(\frac{sin 4\theta}{r^4})$.

Then use Cauchy Riemann equations in polar form are: $\partial u/\partial r=\partial v/r\partial \theta,\partial v/\partial r=-\partial u/r\partial \theta$

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy. For example, $\frac {f(h+i0)-f(0)} h=\frac {e^{-h^{-4}}} h$ and the limit as  $h \to 0$ through real values is $0$. [ $e^{x^{4}} \to \infty$ faster than any power of $x$ as $x \to \infty$. Put $x=\frac 1 h$].  For partial derivatives w.r.t. $y$ we get the same limit since $i^{4}=1$.

Comment: It is given as $exp(-z^{-4})$

Answer (score 0):

A function $f$ is holomorphic at $z$ if $\lim_{|h| \to 0} \frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}$ exists. This equation is more fundamental than the Cauchy-Riemann equations, which are derived from this.

In the actual case we get
$$
f'(0) 
= \lim_{|h| \to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} 
= \lim_{|h| \to 0} \frac{e^{-h^{-4}}}{h}
= \{ R = 1/h \}
= \lim_{|R| \to \infty} R e^{-R^{4}}
.
$$

When we take partial derivatives, $h$ follows an axis. Then so does $R$ and we have $R^4 = |R|^4.$ This leads to $|R e^{-R^{4}}| = |R| e^{-|R|^{4}} \to 0$ as $|R| \to \infty.$ Thus all partial derivatives are $0$ at $z=0$, which implies that the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied.